# Why doesn't the rest of the code after call() work?

Tags: python, logging, subprocess

I want to be able to store both the inputs and outputs - just everything that I see on the terminal - in a file. I have to do that within the script, and not as a command in the terminal. I have tried doing that using call() at the beginning and end of the script, like so:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["script", "session.log"])

belong = raw_input("Random input getter no.1 ")
take = raw_input("Input getter no.2")
def ok():
    print "OK"

def place():
    print "PLACE"

def hope():
    print "HOPE"
if belong != 'mcr':
    ok()

if take != 'mcrr':
    place()
    hope()

print "random words"
print "more words"


call(["exit"])
```

Please ignore the nonsense phrases, I created those just so the .log file would have something in it.

What happens when I run this is that this message appears on the terminal:

> Script started, file is session.log

Nothing more. I am supposed to be prompted for an input, right? Then I entered:

> exit

on the terminal, then this appeared:

> exit
>
> Script done, file is session.log
>
> Random input getter no.1

Only after typing "exit" on the terminal does the rest of the code actually work. I want the .log file to be created first, then run the entire code, then exit.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `call` line?

Comment: it asks for my input. "Random input getter no.1"

Comment: On what OS are you?

Comment: that cannot work. You have to run `script` in a shell, not in a subprocess. I suppose that it does nothing

Comment: What happens if you keep the first `call`, but comment out the second one?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: If I comment out the 2nd call(), this appears on the terminal: "Script started, file is sessyon.log"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre do you have any suggestions on how to store all input and output in a terminal in one session?

Comment: wrap a python script in `script` session from a mother python script using subprocess... I tried to answer, but it doesn't capture the inputs

Comment: Your Python script isn't exiting; rather the call to `call` runs `script`, which starts a new interactive shell. When you exit that shell, then `call` returns and your Python script continues. If you want `script` to log your Python script, then you need to run *it* from `script`, not vice versa.